# Jasper Report error FirebirdSql Error#50710702

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, firebird

I had a custom report built for me in Jasper for a program we use and when updating the program the report hits an error.  The error is:

ERROR#50710702
iReport is unable to populate (0)

The stack detail is:

```
     com.fbi.util.exception.ExceptionMainFree: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query : 

SELECT part.num AS PartNum, part.description AS PartDescription, part.id AS partid, onhand.lgid,
    COALESCE(sold.qtysold, 0) AS qtySold,
DATEDIFF(day FROM timestamp ? TO timestamp ?) AS datediff,

    COALESCE(onhand.avgqoh, 0) AS AvgQOH, COALESCE(locationgroup.name, 'No Inventory') as LocationGroupName,
                productfortree.num AS productnum, producttree.name AS tree,
    company.name AS company

FROM part
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(inventorylog.qtyonhand) AS avgQOH, inventorylog.partid AS PartID, inventorylog.locationgroupid as LGID
                 FROM inventorylog
                WHERE inventorylog.typeID IN (1,10,15,20,30,40,50,60,64,67,68,72)
                  AND inventorylog.eventdate BETWEEN ? AND ?
                GROUP BY inventorylog.partid, inventorylog.locationgroupid) onHand ON part.id = onhand.partid
    LEFT JOIN locationgroup ON onhand.lgid = locationgroup.id
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT product.partid AS PartID, SUM(soitem.qtyfulfilled) AS QtySold, so.locationgroupid AS LGID
                 FROM soitem
                 LEFT JOIN product ON soitem.productid = product.id
                 LEFT JOIN so ON so.id = soitem.soid
                WHERE soitem.typeid = 10
                  AND soitem.datelastfulfillment BETWEEN ? AND ?
                GROUP BY product.partid, so.locationgroupid) AS sold ON part.id = sold.partid AND locationgroup.id = sold.lgid
    LEFT JOIN product AS productfortree ON productfortree.partid = part.id
    LEFT JOIN producttotree ON producttotree.productid = productfortree.id
    LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttree.id = producttotree.producttreeid
    JOIN company ON company.id = 1

WHERE part.activeflag = 1
    AND part.typeid = 10
    AND locationgroup.id IN (7,8,9)
    AND part.num LIKE ?
    AND ((COALESCE(producttree.id,0) IN (0)) OR ((COALESCE(producttree.id,0) LIKE ?)))

GROUP BY producttree.name, part.description, part.id, onhand.lgid, COALESCE(sold.qtysold, 0),
DATEDIFF(day FROM timestamp ? TO timestamp ?),
COALESCE(onhand.avgqoh, 0), COALESCE(locationgroup.name, 'No Inventory'),
productfortree.num, part.num, company.name

ORDER BY producttree.name, part.num


                at com.evnt.eve.modules.logic.extra.LogicReport.getJasperPrint(LogicReport.java:300)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.ReportModule.getJasperPrint(ReportModule.java:168)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule.handleEvent(EVEModule.java:189)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.handleEvent(MessageHandler.java:156)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.run(MessageHandler.java:115)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query : 

SELECT part.num AS PartNum, part.description AS PartDescription, part.id AS partid, onhand.lgid,
    COALESCE(sold.qtysold, 0) AS qtySold,
DATEDIFF(day FROM timestamp ? TO timestamp ?) AS datediff,

    COALESCE(onhand.avgqoh, 0) AS AvgQOH, COALESCE(locationgroup.name, 'No Inventory') as LocationGroupName,
                productfortree.num AS productnum, producttree.name AS tree,
    company.name AS company

FROM part
    INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(inventorylog.qtyonhand) AS avgQOH, inventorylog.partid AS PartID, inventorylog.locationgroupid as LGID
                 FROM inventorylog
                WHERE inventorylog.typeID IN (1,10,15,20,30,40,50,60,64,67,68,72)
                  AND inventorylog.eventdate BETWEEN ? AND ?
                GROUP BY inventorylog.partid, inventorylog.locationgroupid) onHand ON part.id = onhand.partid
    LEFT JOIN locationgroup ON onhand.lgid = locationgroup.id
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT product.partid AS PartID, SUM(soitem.qtyfulfilled) AS QtySold, so.locationgroupid AS LGID
                 FROM soitem
                 LEFT JOIN product ON soitem.productid = product.id
                 LEFT JOIN so ON so.id = soitem.soid
                WHERE soitem.typeid = 10
                  AND soitem.datelastfulfillment BETWEEN ? AND ?
                GROUP BY product.partid, so.locationgroupid) AS sold ON part.id = sold.partid AND locationgroup.id = sold.lgid
    LEFT JOIN product AS productfortree ON productfortree.partid = part.id
    LEFT JOIN producttotree ON producttotree.productid = productfortree.id
    LEFT JOIN producttree ON producttree.id = producttotree.producttreeid
    JOIN company ON company.id = 1

WHERE part.activeflag = 1
    AND part.typeid = 10
    AND locationgroup.id IN (7,8,9)
    AND part.num LIKE ?
    AND ((COALESCE(producttree.id,0) IN (0)) OR ((COALESCE(producttree.id,0) LIKE ?)))

GROUP BY producttree.name, part.description, part.id, onhand.lgid, COALESCE(sold.qtysold, 0),
DATEDIFF(day FROM timestamp ? TO timestamp ?),
COALESCE(onhand.avgqoh, 0), COALESCE(locationgroup.name, 'No Inventory'),
productfortree.num, part.num, company.name

ORDER BY producttree.name, part.num


                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:377)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1087)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:668)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.logic.extra.LogicReport.getJasperPrint(LogicReport.java:296)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.ReportModule.getJasperPrint(ReportModule.java:168)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule.handleEvent(EVEModule.java:189)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.handleEvent(MessageHandler.java:156)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.run(MessageHandler.java:115)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 3, column 29
?
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:138)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBPreparedStatement.<init>(FBPreparedStatement.java:45)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatementFactory.createPreparedStatement(FBStatementFactory.java:89)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:1187)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:942)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:896)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:324)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:267)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1087)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:668)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.logic.extra.LogicReport.getJasperPrint(LogicReport.java:296)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.ReportModule.getJasperPrint(ReportModule.java:168)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule.handleEvent(EVEModule.java:189)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.handleEvent(MessageHandler.java:156)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.run(MessageHandler.java:115)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 3, column 29
?
                at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092)
                at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042)
                at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlPrepare(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1465)
                at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSHelper.prepareStatement(GDSHelper.java:190)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractStatement.java:1441)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.prepareFixedStatement(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:1285)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.<init>(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:135)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBPreparedStatement.<init>(FBPreparedStatement.java:45)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatementFactory.createPreparedStatement(FBStatementFactory.java:89)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:1187)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:942)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:896)
                at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.prepareStatement(AbstractConnection.java:324)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:267)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1087)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:668)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
                at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:849)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.logic.extra.LogicReport.getJasperPrint(LogicReport.java:296)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.ReportModule.getJasperPrint(ReportModule.java:168)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule.handleEvent(EVEModule.java:189)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.handleEvent(MessageHandler.java:156)
                at com.evnt.eve.MessageHandler.run(MessageHandler.java:115)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
DATEDIFF(day FROM timestamp ? TO timestamp ?) AS datediff
```

The `timestamp` shorthand cast is only valid if immediately followed by a string literal in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. As you use a parameter instead you need to cast the parameter to the required type:

```
DATEDIFF(day FROM CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP) TO CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP)) AS datediff
```

Maybe you even need to double cast:

```
CAST(CAST(? AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I changed the code and still got the error.

Comment: Here is what the source looks like:  CODE:                                 DATEDIFF(day FROM CAST($P{dateRange1} AS TIMESTAMP) TO CAST($P{dateRange2} AS TIMESTAMP)) AS datediff,

Comment: @JCWonder have you tried the double cast as I suggested?

Comment: @JCWonder Another possibility is that you are using Firebird 1.5 or earlier. The ability to cast parameters was added in Firebird 2.0.